# ubuntu18 failed to autostart python script which import redis

Tags: python, redis, autostart

```
import time
import os
os.system('mkdir /home/zh/testdir')

import redis
r = redis.Redis()
os.system('mkdir /home/zh/testdir2')
r.lpush('key1',i)
os.system('mkdir /home/zh/testdir3')
```

Above code worked when I run it from the terminal.

But if I add it to startup applications, the part behind 'os.system('mkdir /home/zh/testdir')' didn't work.

I've enabled redis-server.service.

Any suggestions would be very grateful!

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn’t work"?

Comment: means /home/zh/testdir2 not created